# How many non-hostile creatures are affected by the Hobgoblin Captain's Leadership action?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, actions

Looking at the 5e MM, I'm not sure how many non-hostile creatures are affected by the Hobgoblin Captain's Leadership action - only one, or all of them within 30'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## There is no limit to the number of creatures that can be affected

[The Leadership action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/hobgoblin-captain) states the effect can be activated:

> whenever a nonhostile creature that it can see within 30 feet of it makes an attack roll or a saving throw.

There is no limit to the number of times this can be activated during the 1-minute duration. It can be used on 1 creature, 100 creatures, the same creature 100 times.

The only restrictions are that they are within 30 feet, can hear and understand the captain, are not already benefiting from leadership (eg if there are two Hobgoblin Captains at the same time, they can't both buff the same roll), and the captain isn't incapacitated.

Comment: So, at the time of the command any ally within 30' of the hobgoblin will get +1d4 on attacks for the next ten rounds, correct?

Comment: @RockStone Not quite. For the next 10 rounds any ally that makes an attack roll or a saving throw within 30ft can have +1d4. If an ally was within 30ft when the Captain activated their ability but moves to be 40ft away, then they are out of range when they attack and the Captain can't give them a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

[image: 30 ft from the leader]

so 92 medium sized creatures can benefit from the buff, but if you move some of them out of it's radius after they attack and move others in.. the number increases slightly.. taking into account that melee/ranged matters and you can't replace/rotate to every spot each turn.. I's say it's roughly +50% more so the number increases to ~140ish